# group by date java

Tags: java, group-by

I have a csv-file with some 500k observation of format "date(LocalDate);hour;value;type". I am supposed to perform operations on this data such as finding average values, counting missing values the type of value for a date interval.

I can construct hourly observation objects while looping through the strings list:

```
new HourlyObs(date,hour,val,type);
```

These observations are hourly (though not 24 obs per day as some data is missing), but I think it would be easier to group them by date and then perform some binary searches, given the functionality I'm supposed to implement.

So my thoughts were to create an array of objects, where the objects are designed as follows:

```
class DailyObservation {

private LocalDate date;
private ArrayList<HourlyObs>; 

public float avgVal();
public int missingVals();
public float nrOfType();}
```

Is there an "easy" and efficient algorithm for creating this array of daily observations? I can't wrap my head around it and I am not allowed to use streams for aggregation. 
Many thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the data sorted?

If it is sorted then you can just iterate over it, track the date change and create new objects accordingly.

If the data isn't sorted then probably the best idea would be to create a Map where date is the key and `DailyObservation` is the value. For each entry of the data you check if an object already exists in the Map for a given date.

Edit:

For a sorted data you could try something like this:

```
public List<DailyObservation> parseObservations(){
    List<DailyObservation> results = new ArrayList<>();
    DailyObservation current = new DailyObservation();
    String[] line;

    while((line=readLine()) != null){
        String dateString = line[0];
        LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse(dateString);

        if (!localDate.equals(current.getDate())){
            current = new DailyObservation();
            results.add(current);
        }

        HourlyObs hourlyObs = new HourlyObs();
        //
        //  assign data from lie to the hourlyObs however you want
        //      
        current.addHourlyObs(hourlyObs);
    }
    return results;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, yes, the data is sorted. I tried with iteration but didn't get the expected results, since an object is then created at every step. I suppose I would need one created at every distinct date, but I didn't succeed in doing that while adding the hourly observations into the daily objects. If I have a list of 27k distinct days and 500k hourly obs, the amount of operations in the nested loop for date equality checking becomes enormous. Is there any more efficient way other than brute force?

Comment: @J.Dow I've edited my answer, check if it works for you.

Comment: Thank you very much, exactly what I was looking for.